# Is there a way to force the dark mode of Mac third-party apps that do not have it?

Tags: macos, dark-mode

I am a huge fan of dark mode, and I am wondering if there is a way to have dark mode on apps that have not implemented it yet.

Comment: How?  Such an app would not have the theme elements.  This is different than trying to get a web browser to force it, which is rendering at display time and all you have to do is invert the colors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, note that apps which do not natively support dark mode will likely contain elements which do not coordinate with the new theme, so doing this will be less effective than if the developer were to update their app.

1. Quit your app.
2. Determine the app's bundle identifier: `grep -A 1 CFBundleIdentifier /path/to/your/application.app/Contents/Info.plist`
3. `defaults write BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool false`

where you would replace `BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` with the actual value from step 2 (e.g., `com.apple.TextEdit`).